# Best way to export delta data of a transactional table

Tags: sql-server

Following is the requirement for my table say "Orders":
1) On day-1, I am sending the full data using bcp command as a unicode text file.
2) From the next day daily, I need to send only delta data for the transactions happenned that day.
What is the best way to implement delta? I would like to avoid the current table design and not all table has timestamp fields.

Comment: i suggest you save the bcp file from day 1 in a save place (may you only want to save the primary keys of the affected rows). on day 2 you could then do again a bcp and compare the new file against the file from day 1 and remove the rows not needed...the same can then be done for the next day and so on...

Comment: Hi dom. It has to be automated. And changes could be Addition of a new row, Deletion of a row, Update on a row.

Comment: write a perl / shell script for it? I did not mean to do these steps manually ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into SQL Server change tracking. It does what you want.

You could also snapshot the PK values and a hash of each row on midnight. Next night you snapshot again and create the diff using a full join.

Comment: Up vote for an interesting idea, but technically that still requires altering the tables.

Comment: It does not require altering the table. You create a *new* table that holds the PK values and hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You've already excluded the best way. Now you are limited to manually performing a diff based on the previous day's snapshot.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. What is that best way? Please edit your answer if you feel that is the best way even if it impacts the current design. Manual diff is a big No.